# How to sync only those photos that were taken this year?

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, photos, macos

In my Photos.app (Mac), photos were taken from 2013, all of which are supposed to be synced to iCloud since OS X upgraded to EL Capitan.

It's not possible to sync all to my iPhone because the total photo library size is bigger than 5G.

Is there a selective sync tool to determine only this year's photos or some could be synced rather than all of them?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify in iTunes, whilst the phone is connected.

Select your device at the top, then in the left-hand column, select Photos.
You can choose any or all Albums, Faces etc in the lower half of the screen [not shown] & additionally a specific time period to include all photos from.

[image]

Comment: Looks smart. But I can't find these config on my side, there's nothing. http://i.stack.imgur.com/JWDXp.png

Comment: Ahh… never used iCloud for photos, always done it manually [don't trust it, tbh, prefer to know where all my data actually is]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an album with only last year photos (for example) and then sync only this album to your iPhone. When you connect it to the PC, in iTunes you can choose only one album to be synced, instead of the whole library.