# Push photo from MacBook to iPhone via USB

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, photos, usb

I can drag and drop an image from a folder on my MacBook into Photos. Now I want to push it to the photos on my iPhone. They are connect by USB.

I don't want to mess with clouds in the "interweb". Just move it 80cm along a wire from one of my very expensive apple devices to another.

There must be a better way than photographing my laptop screen!

**edit 1:** I'm looking for a way to do this "normally" meaning using the standard Apple features on my phone and laptop - thanks!

**edit 2:** A simple example; *taking photos of my MacBook screen* because I don't know how to push a screen capture to my phone seamlessly!

Comment: iTunes sync has some filters for what to push across - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214649/how-to-sync-only-those-photos-that-were-taken-this-year/214658#214658

Answer (score 1):

Any USB file transfer application should do that. What works for me is using TDownloader [Free, appstore].

Go to iTunes (on your Mac) then click on your iPhone > Applications and scroll all the way down to "file transfer".

Then, drag your photos to the application's folder and you're done. 
The only thing left would be to go to the App and save those photos to the Library.

I have been looking for a more simple way for long, but until now that's all I've found that's reliable.

Comment: Thanks! But I think the Apple environment can (or should) do this. I don't want to use the cloud and definitely don't want to install 3rd party software!

Answer (score 1):

You can use iTunes to sync photos already imported into iPhoto, Aperture, Photos and Image Capture, as well as sync photos from a folder of images on your computer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That sounds good! I have never synched my phone and laptop. Can I use this to move one picture only, or will iTunes suddenly start synching a bunch of things weather I like it or not?

Comment: You can put one photo in a folder anywhere on your Mac and from the <b>Choose folder...</b> option (selected in the second screen shot), sync that photo to your iPhone.